# How to access child class from parent class in web scraping using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-science

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
data={"title":[],"price":[]}
header={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)         Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
url="https://www.amazon.in/deals?ref_=nav_cs_gb"
response=requests.get(url,headers=header)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
whole=soup.find("div" ,{"class":"jumbo-tracker"})
name=whole.select("h4.sc-1hp8d8a-0.sc-lffWgi.flnmvC")
print(name)
```

This is what i have done so far. I can't figure out why I am getting nonetype when  there is already a class in zomato website and inspect element .
please go through the link in url and please help me to find the name of resturants .

Comment: Are you sure there are name of restorants on amazon ?

Comment: There's no such `div` with `"class":"jumbo-tracker"` on the mentioned `url`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are trying to access the name elements using the whole.select() method. However, the reason you are getting NoneType is that the whole variable is None itself, indicating that the find() method didn't find any element with the specified class.

The issue is likely because the website's content is dynamically loaded using JavaScript, and the initial HTML response might not contain the data you are trying to scrape. BeautifulSoup does not execute JavaScript, so it cannot handle dynamic content.
Here's how you can modify your code to use Selenium along with BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

data = {"title": [], "price": []}

# Set up the Chrome driver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")  # Disable GPU acceleration to avoid some issues
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "https://www.amazon.in/deals?ref_=nav_cs_gb"

# Navigate to the URL using the Chrome driver
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the page to load and the dynamic content to be rendered (adjust the wait time as needed)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# Get the page source after the content is loaded
page_source = driver.page_source

# Close the driver
driver.quit()

# Use BeautifulSoup to parse the page source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")

# Now you can access the desired elements as before
whole = soup.find("div", {"class": "jumbo-tracker"})
if whole:
    name = whole.select("h4.sc-1hp8d8a-0.sc-lffWgi.flnmvC")
    print(name)
else:
    print("Data not found on the page.")
```

In this code, we use Selenium to load the webpage and wait for the dynamic content to be rendered before fetching the page source. Then, we use BeautifulSoup to parse the page source and extract the desired elements.